# Distribution of $1/\sqrt{X}$ when $X$ is a gamma variate

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, posterior, inverse-gamma-distribution

It is a question about finding the posterior parameters.

$X$ follows $\text{Gamma}(a,b)$ ----(Prior)

$y \vert x$ follows $\text{normal}(\mu,1/x)$  ----- (likelihood), that is variance $(\sigma^2) = 1/x$

The posterior distribution of $X$ is $\text{gamma}( a+n/2, b+(1/2)\sum(x_i-\mu)^2 )$
and of $1/x$ (variance) is $\text{invgamma}( a+n/2, b+(1/2)\sum(x_i-\mu)^2) $, it is the same except the change in the distributions.

I tried to solve for the posterior distribution of $1/(x^{1/2})$ but I am unable to find the value of the beta parameter, I got the alpha parameter to be $(2a)$ which I highly doubt to be right.

Comment: Please format your equations using MathJax.

Comment: Please show how "tried to solve for" the posterior.  This is, after all, a straightforward application of a change of variables formula, so the best resolution for you would be to detect the step at which you erred or got stuck.

Comment: When given the distribution of $W=1/X$, wirh $X>0$ with probability one, finding the distribution of $Z=1/√X$ is a mere change of variable, with Jacobian $2z$.

Comment: Some related Qs: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54633/is-a-power-of-an-inverse-gamma-random-variable-itself-inverse-gamma,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277567/variation-on-inverse-gamma-1-xr-inv-gamma,